# mysql database design full-text question

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a legacy mysql database and there's this table which has a few full-text indexed columns. In each of these columns the data stored is separated by space. It's like

```
token1 token2 token3
```

with the full-text index functioning, the code does a match as:

```
SELECT ... FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(column1) AGAINST('token1' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND MATCH(column2) AGAINST('token2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND MATCH(column3) AGAINST('token3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Now I want to refacter this particular design into a more normalized fashion. Another reason is that I want to use innoDB tables instead myism ones. The process seems to convert each column into one attribute table and then use another connect table to mark the one to many relationship between the attribute table and the original table. This would probably complicates the SQL a lot. I'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: this is basic requirement for Normalization that each column must have one value not multiple..., so need to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you should create a many-many relation between your tables. That way you will obtain a better performance and a lot of more flexibility.